# what can i use instead of System.Web.Services.Description in Silverlight Windows Phone 7 app?

Tags: c#, web-services, silverlight, windows-phone-7, soap-client

I use a web service like "myservice/XXX/mobile.asmx"
and I have to change the XXX with user input. but how should I do this, I couldn't get answer in my previous  post
[How to change the service reference throughout the code in Windows Phone 7 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184076/how-to-change-the-service-reference-throughout-the-code-in-windows-phone-7-app)

Well, I can do the same thing with generating the service code everytime user logged-in, but I  have to use 
System.Web.Services.Description

anyone knows one way of two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched the internet for 3 days and found no solution.

Clearly, Windows phone 7 doesn't support System.Web library. So, when a developer wants to generate the code from web service to a library(.dll) and use the methods from generated library with using  `System.Web.Services.Description`  , he cannot achieve this by any means. There is no solution for this. 
However, developer can change the endpoint adress of the soap client. 
with using

```
SoapClient.Endpoint.Adress =
     new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress (" http://xxx/myservice.asmx" );
```

This code block change the service reference in runtime. But, it doesn't change the service reference's endpoint for all project. Developer must use this code in every page(or save the soap client ,which had been updated, to isolated storage and use it from there). And if the endpoint have different implementation from the original one it doesn't work.